# iFrame preventing Custom Search Engine data in Google Analytics

Tags: google-search, google-search-api, google-custom-search

Here is our website, http://www.tbvets.org/

In the top right is the Google Custom Search implementation.

Search, for example, "Donate", and inspect the pop-up and you will see the following,
**Donate** Now - TB Vets Charitable Foundation

The search query parameter is "q".

Here is my setup in Google Analytics for the URL which uses Google CSE.

[image: Google Analytics Site Search Query Parameter]

All sites are verified as owned on Google Search console, and they have been linked to the Google Analytics account.

[image: Linked to GA]

I've performed many test searches over the past couple weeks (searches, and followed through on links), and here are the results under Behavior-->Site Search-->Usage,

[image: GA Site Search - No Results]

Edit: Additional Notes

- The search field is in a static position on every page.
- The search results appear in an overlay, via an iframe of Google's
  machination.
- The iframe appears upon being called by clicking search.
- The iframe has a variable id, and a starting value of 'master-x'.
- further searches increase the value of 'master-x' by 1.
- Reloading the page changes the id to 'slave-x-y' where 'x' was the last value of 'x' in master and 'y' is a new integer starting at 1 for slave.

Here's some sample code:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" width="100%" name="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;master-1&quot;,&quot;slave-1-1&quot;:{&quot;linkTarget&quot;:&quot;_top&quot;,&quot;lines&quot;:3,&quot;fontSizeTitle&quot;:&quot;16px&quot;,&quot;fontSizeDescription&quot;:&quot;13px&quot;,&quot;fontSizeDomainLink&quot;:&quot;13px&quot;,&quot;position&quot;:&quot;right&quot;,&quot;cseGoogleHosting&quot;:&quot;partner&quot;,&quot;adIconLocation&quot;:&quot;ad-left&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;ads&quot;,&quot;columns&quot;:1,&quot;horizontalAlignment&quot;:&quot;left&quot;,&quot;resultsPageQueryParam&quot;:&quot;query&quot;},&quot;master-1&quot;:{&quot;linkTarget&quot;:&quot;_top&quot;,&quot;lines&quot;:3,&quot;fontSizeTitle&quot;:&quot;16px&quot;,&quot;fontSizeDescription&quot;:&quot;13px&quot;,&quot;fontSizeDomainLink&quot;:&quot;13px&quot;,&quot;position&quot;:&quot;top&quot;,&quot;cseGoogleHosting&quot;:&quot;partner&quot;,&quot;adIconLocation&quot;:&quot;ad-left&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;ads&quot;,&quot;columns&quot;:1,&quot;horizontalAlignment&quot;:&quot;left&quot;,&quot;resultsPageQueryParam&quot;:&quot;query&quot;}}"
id="master-1" src="https://cse.google.com/cse?q=search1&amp;r=m&amp;cx=012459647549659385068%3A6plpmyzofqe&amp;fexp=2631602%2C20606%2C7000107%2C4040473&amp;client=google-coop&amp;hl=en&amp;type=0&amp;oe=UTF-8&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;jsei=3&amp;format=p3%7Cn5&amp;ad=n5p3&amp;nocache=1941450461188788&amp;num=0&amp;output=uds_ads_only&amp;source=gcsc&amp;v=3&amp;allwcallad=1&amp;adext=as1%2Csr1%2Cctc1&amp;bsl=10&amp;u_his=4&amp;u_tz=-480&amp;dt=1450461188790&amp;u_w=1920&amp;u_h=1080&amp;biw=1903&amp;bih=995&amp;psw=1903&amp;psh=995&amp;frm=0&amp;uio=uv3vp1sd13sv13st16sl1sr1cc1-lh-&amp;rurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tbvets.org%2F#master-1"
style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px;"></iframe>
```

And here's a reload page, then search, sample code:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" width="100%" name="slave-1-1|{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;master-1&quot;,&quot;slave-1-1&quot;:{&quot;linkTarget&quot;:&quot;_top&quot;,&quot;lines&quot;:3,&quot;fontSizeTitle&quot;:&quot;16px&quot;,&quot;fontSizeDescription&quot;:&quot;13px&quot;,&quot;fontSizeDomainLink&quot;:&quot;13px&quot;,&quot;position&quot;:&quot;right&quot;,&quot;cseGoogleHosting&quot;:&quot;partner&quot;,&quot;adIconLocation&quot;:&quot;ad-left&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;ads&quot;,&quot;columns&quot;:1,&quot;horizontalAlignment&quot;:&quot;left&quot;,&quot;resultsPageQueryParam&quot;:&quot;query&quot;},&quot;master-1&quot;:{&quot;linkTarget&quot;:&quot;_top&quot;,&quot;lines&quot;:3,&quot;fontSizeTitle&quot;:&quot;16px&quot;,&quot;fontSizeDescription&quot;:&quot;13px&quot;,&quot;fontSizeDomainLink&quot;:&quot;13px&quot;,&quot;position&quot;:&quot;top&quot;,&quot;cseGoogleHosting&quot;:&quot;partner&quot;,&quot;adIconLocation&quot;:&quot;ad-left&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;ads&quot;,&quot;columns&quot;:1,&quot;horizontalAlignment&quot;:&quot;left&quot;,&quot;resultsPageQueryParam&quot;:&quot;query&quot;}}"
id="slave-1-1" src="https://cse.google.com/cse?q=search4&amp;r=s&amp;cx=012459647549659385068%3A6plpmyzofqe&amp;client=google-coop&amp;hl=en&amp;type=0&amp;oe=UTF-8&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;fexp=20606%2C7000107%2C4040473&amp;jsei=3&amp;format=n5&amp;ad=n0&amp;nocache=3721450462023686&amp;num=0&amp;output=uds_ads_only&amp;source=gcsc&amp;v=3&amp;allwcallad=1&amp;adext=as1%2Csr1%2Cctc1&amp;bsl=10&amp;rurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tbvets.org%2F#slave-1-1"
style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: I believe that site search reports get populated when the search is done through the site itself, and not through a 3rd party. What the search settings above do is to track the search term entered only if you are pushing that into the URL (so that GA and pick that out).

Comment: So I need to embed the search without an iFrame or overlay then?